# How to upload photo to web site and getting its url

Tags: c#, image, upload

The idea is to choose photo in c# windows forms application by openfiledialog ,then uploading this photo to a certain website , and getting its link.

after that I can see the photo by navigating to its url .

can I achieve that ?

Comment: I'm just asking if it's possible to do that , if so , how to start ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. To do the upload, that website has to be able to accept the photo, either via API, or FTP, or whatever; you can't just randomly upload a photo to any website :) If that's taken care of then your approach to upload it will depend on how the website accepts the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need FTP Username and Password to access to Your Website Folders

You need  the FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse classes. The reason to use these classes instead of using WebClient classes is that if you use FtpWebRequest/Response classes to upload and download files then we have more control of what is done inside.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

Try this code to upload:

```
FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo("FileName");                                                  
System.Net.FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://serverip/FileName");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;                                             
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName","Password");                            
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();                                                 
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(files);                                                        
int length = 1024;                                                                             
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];                                                              
int bytesRead = 0;                                                                             
do                                                                                             
{                                                                                              
    bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);                                                  
    ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);                                                     
}                                                                                              
while (bytesRead != 0);                                                                        
file.Close();                                                                                  
ftpStream.Close();
```

Comment: thanx for that, I'm starting to understand,but how to make a user name and password ?,,,,and you mean by this "ftp://serverip/FileName" to replace it with the website that I upload from ?

Comment: first you need to have ftp account on your website's server to access to folders for write and replace "ftp://serverip/FileName" to your folder ftp path